# Assigning System.currentTimeMillis() within a Swing Timer's Action Listener back to an uninitialized long variable

Tags: java, swing, variables, timer, actionlistener

I am currently playing around with a server and client. I want my server to be polling the current system time every second. I am currently using a Swing timer to assign the currentTimeMillis() back to an uninitialized long outside the timer's Action Listener. Currently when I attempt to do this, Eclipse asks me to give the long time a final status, yet as this needs to be polling and changing, that is not viable. The idea is then that this long will be told to get sent through the socket to the client. How can I get this working with my current code? Or if there is a better way to do this, how can I do it? Thanks very much for your help!

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Server {


public static void main(String[] args) {

      long time;

      ActionListener listener = new ActionListener(){
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
              time = System.currentTimeMillis();          
          }
        };
        Timer currentTime = new Timer(1000, listener);
        currentTime.start();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make `time` a field of the class. (In fact there is no sence placing it in main!

Or you could make `final AtomicLong time = new AtomicLong();`.

Comment: Thanks, I think that I got my problem sorted. It was where I was placing time! Stupid mistake!